# KeychainItemWrapper Arcified

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I've downloaded the latest version of KeyChainItemWrapper from GitHub, but when compiling it gives me this error: THIS CODE MUST BE COMPILED WITH ARC ENABLED!

So, I tried to Arcified my project by going to: Edit-->Refactor-->Convert to Objective-C ARC,
and run the converter, but it gives me the same error...

the origin of this error is from this code that exists in the KeyChainItemWrapper.m

```
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error THIS CODE MUST BE COMPILED WITH ARC ENABLED!
#endif
```

How can I turn objc_arc feature ??

Thanks!

Comment: Check this https://devforums.apple.com/message/533729#533729. You need to login to view that.

Comment: Get the original non-ARC KeychainItemWrapper class from the GenericKeychain example app from Apple.

Comment: Why do you recommend to take the non-ARC version?? isn't using ARC better to avoid releasing and leaking??

Comment: @Shvalb I assume you were responding to me. I thought you had a non-ARC project and were having problems with the ARC version of `KeychainItemWrapper`. You made it sound like you only tried to convert to ARC since you had the ARC version of `KeychainItemWrapper`. So I suggested the non-ARC `KeychainItemWrapper`. Xcode's ARC conversion tool is a real pain if you have some ARC code mixed in with your non-ARC code you are trying to convert. If you have all non-ARC code, the conversion will be much easier.

Comment: @rmaddy : do you have any link to ARC version of KeychainItemWrapper ?

Comment: @Xman I believe there is one on github.

Comment: @rmaddy : ya got it... I had it but I forgot to add security framework that's why it wasn't working. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Go into build phases, Compile Sources, find the source for that file, double click and add "-fobjc-arc" for it's flags :). That will let you compile only that file with arc and use it in non-arc projects

Comment: If that was true, you wouldn't be getting this error. Double check. :P

Answer (score 0):

This was posted a while, but I had the same issue so I'll post it here.

If you have ARC-enabled code already in your project when you convert, it will throw an error. Just comment out the lines so that they read:

```
/*#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#error THIS CODE MUST BE COMPILED WITH ARC ENABLED!
#endif*/
```

Continue attempting to convert to ARC, and un-comment after it succeeds in converting.